# How can i have my app make a folder on the SD and include an image?

Tags: android

I need my App to make a folder on the SD card and in the folder it need to include an image.

How would i go about doing this?

-

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your code you can use

```
// create a File object for the parent directory
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/[folderName]/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

it will create a folder in your sdcard in the name of MyFoler and the create a new .png file...

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile().toString()+"/MyFolder").mkdir();
            File file = new File(Environment
                     .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyFolder/img_dinash" + ".png");


                    try{
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
                      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                      out.flush(); out.close();
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
```